# Significant numerical meaning was changed without OP feedback

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/100848/i-declined-an-offer-from-an-employer-months-ago-i-am-interviewing-again), there was a recent edit that changed

> 75 cent raise

to

> 75 percent raise

Without any feedback from the OP.

In all honesty, I find 75 percent raises outright unbelievable in this context.  The question is about the OP looking to leave said company.

Should this be rolled back?  Logically the 75 cent raise is WAY more likely than a completely unannounced 75% raise.

Comment: Why even ask? It's an anonymous user that turned cent into percent which is a drastic and unsubstantiated change. Just roll that back if you see it. I've just adjusted it.

Comment: I thought the edit was approved by 2 other people, so I wasn't sure if reverting it was the right thing to do.

Comment: Suggested edits are usually viewed in isolation. Reviewers likely assumed that the OP clarified it was a percentage in the comments when he didn't. Edits aren't supposed to unilaterally change details and people rarely submit such edits so it's not abnormal that this was approved. But when you see the full context of the question and realise that an anonymous(!) user adjusted this based on zero evidence it's fine to just revert that. Raising it on meta is fine but usually overkill. You can also ask in [chat] for stuff like this if you're not sure but don't want to create a full meta post.

Comment: The raise doesn't appear to have any impact whatsoever on the question or the answers, so I removed that part. The mentions of promotion and turnover rate can arguably be removed too.